# Changing DASH Parameters in FFmpeg on the fly?

Tags: ffmpeg, live, mpeg-dash

I am using FFmpeg to create MPEG dash segments from my camera and playing it using Shaka Player. But I want to change the segment size (For example 2 seconds to 1 second) without creating a new process and without exiting the current process. Is there a change to change the parameter value in FFmpeg on the fly?

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1280x720  -rtbufsize 100M  -r 30  -i 0 -qscale 100 -g 1 -vcodec libx264 seg_duration 1 -f dash -use_timeline 0 -use_template 0 -single_file 0 ffmpeg.mpd
```

This is the command where I want to change the segment_duration to 2, without exiting the current process.

ie.

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1280x720  -rtbufsize 100M  -r 30  -i 0 -qscale 100 -g 1 -vcodec libx264 -seg_duration 2 -f dash -use_timeline 0 -use_template 0 -single_file 0 ffmpeg.mpd
```

Or is there any other MPEG DASH Encoder for this use case?

Comment: Ffmpeg does not have that feature.

Comment: Is there any other way to change this on the fly, like changing the key frame interval or gop? Or this there any mpeg dash encoder to do this? I am doing live streaming.